# How favorite list stays the same when you exit the application in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created a database with sqflite on the user's phone. The words entered by the user are saved in the main list.

When you press the icon next to it, it is added to the favorite list, but when the user exits the application, the favorite list is reset.

The main list is the same, there is no problem with it.

When a word is deleted from the main list, it is also deleted from the favorite. But the only problem is that when the favorite list comes out and enters, it resets and writes blank.

How can I make the favorite list stay the same when I exit the application?

This is home page dart file.

```dart
class WordList extends StatefulWidget {
  const WordList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WordListState();
  }
}

class _WordListState extends State {
  var dbHelper = DbHelper();

  List<Word> words;
  List<Word> favoriteWords = [];
  int wordCount = 0;
  int fwordCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getWords();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: Text(
            "ShopList",
            style: GoogleFonts.caveat(
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 35,
                letterSpacing: 1,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          leading: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          bottom: const TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
            automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: false,
            labelColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(7), topRight: Radius.circular(7)),
                color: Colors.white),
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.article_rounded),
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            goToWordAdd();
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          tooltip: "Add New Item",
          splashColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: wordCount,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                return Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: SelectableText(
                              words[position].word,
                              cursorColor: Colors.purple,
                              showCursor: false,
                              toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
                                  copy: true,
                                  selectAll: true,
                                  cut: false,
                                  paste: false),
                              style: GoogleFonts.caveat(
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            subtitle: SelectableText(
                              words[position].description,
                              cursorColor: Colors.purple,
                              showCursor: false,
                              toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
                                  copy: true,
                                  selectAll: true,
                                  cut: false,
                                  paste: false),
                              style: GoogleFonts.caveat(
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (!favoriteWords
                                .contains(words[position])) {
                              favoriteWords.add(words[position]);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Colors.deepPurple,
                            ),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                    side: const BorderSide(
                                        color:
                                        Colors.deepPurpleAccent)))),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        tooltip: 'Delete Item',
                        onPressed: () {
                          goToDelete(words[position]);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            favoriteWords.isEmpty
                ? const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Ürünlerini favorilerine ekle, almayı unutma! ',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            )
                : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: fwordCount,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: SelectableText(
                              favoriteWords[index].word,
                              cursorColor: Colors.purple,
                              showCursor: false,
                              toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
                                  copy: true,
                                  selectAll: true,
                                  cut: false,
                                  paste: false),
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                            subtitle: SelectableText(
                              favoriteWords[index].description,
                              cursorColor: Colors.purple,
                              showCursor: false,
                              toolbarOptions: const ToolbarOptions(
                                  copy: true,
                                  selectAll: true,
                                  cut: false,
                                  paste: false),
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            favoriteWords.remove(favoriteWords[index]);
                          });
                        },
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                            Colors.deepPurple,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.remove,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void goToWordAdd() async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WordAdd()));
    if (result != null) {
      if (result) {
        getWords();
      }
    }
  }

  void getWords() {
    var wordsFuture = dbHelper.getWords();
    wordsFuture.then((data) {
      setState(() {
        words = data;
        wordCount = data.length;
      });
    });
  }

  void goToDelete(Word word) async {
    await dbHelper.delete(word.id);
    favoriteWords.remove(word);
    getWords();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your db queries working properly? and make your that the delete query for the specific table not being called while disposing the state or db.

Comment: Save the favorites to the DB? I'm only seeing an array.

Comment: can you see my answer below